# Jquery 1.8.3 + IE 8 Issue + message unexpected call to method or property access

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer-8

Here, I am trying to run code and IE browser is not supporting, Because of such error all page is crashed and not responding. All the java script failed here.

Any suggestion, Please to resolve this issue.

Code description : [image]

While loading of page, it gives error at this place.

Comment: Can you post your HTML and Jquery code where you are facing the issue?

Comment: You question is not very descriptive? Posting code will be a great move to get help with this.

Comment: what error it's throwing ? IMO elem is null.

Comment: Do NOT post an image of the code… it breaks the search ability of this website.  Post the actual code and error message.

Comment: Are you sure that's the line with the error. Based on your given message `Unexpected call to method or property access`, I would expect to see something like `.access` maybe.